# Passing in unbound variables into R functions

Tags: r, dplyr, arguments, interpreter

```
> counties %>% select(state, county, population, poverty)
> # also written as
> select(counties , state, county, population, poverty)
> state
Error: object 'state' not found
```

Hi everyone,

I have a question regarding what exactly is being passed into the select function here, `state`, `county`, `population` and `poverty` are not actually variables bound to the enclosing environment but rather column names of the first element. Which makes the arguments being passed in to the function actually stateful.

Generally, in other languages these keys would be passed in as a string, so I'm just wondering how we ought to reason and think about these unbound variables here! And maybe additionally, how the R interpreter / parser handles this under the hood.

Comment: Check out the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: Within the reference of the data.frame, these column names refer to variables. If you attach the data.frame to your local environment, you will be able to reference them directly. Just attach it with `attach(counties)` and you may use `state` as a variable name in the local envirnoment.

Comment: It is generally not recommended to use `attach()` because it may lead to all sorts of errors, mainly because it leads to mixing up namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of the R-specific non-standard evaluation. This is a quite powerful concept in R and basically means that what you pass in the function `select` is not evaluated directly. Rather, it takes the argument unevaluated and evaluates it later, in the context of the dataframe.

I suggest you read the Advanced R chapter on this http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html.

To further expand on this, look at this example which showcases the basic concept:

```r
expample_dataframe <- data.frame(
  foo = c(1:5),
  bar = c(10:14)
)

foo <- c("any" , "variable", "in", "global", "namespace")

print(foo) 
#> [1] "any"       "variable"  "in"        "global"    "namespace"

select_column <- function(data_frame, column_name){
  column_name <- substitute(column_name)
  eval(column_name, envir = data_frame)
}

select_column(expample_dataframe, foo)
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5

foo
#> [1] "any"       "variable"  "in"        "global"    "namespace"
```

**Explanation**

`substitute()` leaves the input of the function unevaluated, i.e. it references it as a `symbol`. Then we can use the `eval()` function which allows you to evaluate a certain call/symbol inside a certain namespace. And yes, in R dataframes are namespaces. Thus

`eval(column_name, envir = data_frame)` evaluates `column_name` in the context of the dataframe.

This is what goes on behind the scenes of many functions in R.

<sup>Created on 2020-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! This is exactly it! Good reminder that functions arguments as lazily evaluated as well!!